# Невозможно импортировать имя MutableseSequeSace

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пытаюсь собрать программу. При компиляции Python файла выдает такую интересную ошибку:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'MutableSequence' from 'collections'
```

Искал решение, успех был обречен на провал. Возникает такой конфликт при импорте библиотеки messages. Откат версии модуля не решил проблему, изменение версии Python тоже. Ниже прикрепил полный лог, в котором произошла ошибка. Пытался импортировать данную функцию из библиотеки **collections.abc**, но это не помогло. Код программы можно найти [здесь](https://github.com/Windscribe/Desktop-App/blob/master/tools/build_all.py). Заранее огромное спасибо за ответ.

Полный лог ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Desktop-App\tools\build_all.py", line 40, in <module>
    import base.utils as utl
  File "D:\Desktop-App\tools\base\utils.py", line 15, in <module>
    import messages as msg
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\messages\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .api import send
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\messages\api.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .email_ import Email
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\messages\email_.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ._config import check_config_file
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\messages\_config.py", line 8, in <module>
    from collections import MutableSequence
ImportError: cannot import name 'MutableSequence' from 'collections' (D:\Python\lib\collections\__init__.py)
```

Comment: В доках питона пишут, что с версии питона 3.3 `MutableSequence` переехало из `collections` в `collections.abc`. Попробуйте исправить импорт прямо в `messages\_config.py`, если нет возможности посвежее этот `messages` поставить.

Comment: @CrazyElf да, это решило проблему. Также хотел уточнить, как понять за что отвечает функция iutl.GetDependencyBuildRoot("file") если импортируется она из deps.installutils?

Comment: Это я не в курсе, нужно читать документацию по этим пакетам. Оформлю тот свой комментарий как ответ, раз он помог.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html) пишут, что с версии питона `3.3` `MutableSequence` переехало из `collections` в `collections.abc`. Попробуйте исправить импорт прямо в `messages\_config.py`, если нет возможности посвежее этот `messages` поставить, чтобы он был совместим с питоном версии `3.3` или выше.